# What would happen if the moon was nudged so that its distance to Earth was smaller than the Earth's orbital radius?

Tags: gravity

We know it'd descend to Earth, but what else would happen?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean smaller than "the present orbital radius of the moon around the earth"? For that matter would it descend to Earth necessarily? If you only make the distance smaller by a small amount, the orbit will become more elliptical (more eccentric), for instance...

Answer (score 2):

If you mean within an earth radius, then the moon would break apart, pretty darn fast too.

More here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit

and here: http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/smith/Astro150/Tutorials/Roche/

The earth/moon Roche limit is about 1.49 earth radii (from the surface, not the center), so a bit under 10,000 KM.

If you have the moon outside the Roche Limit, but not far outside, lets say 13,000 KM above the surface (19,370 KM from the center).    Then you'd have a different set of problems.

The moon's current distance, about 384,000 KM - so in terms of view from the surface, it's about 30 times as close, or about 15 degrees in the sky (currently the moon is about 1/2 of a degree).   That's about the size of a grapefruit head at arms length - maybe a large grapefruit if you have long arms.   There would almost never be a full moon as the earth's shadow would get in the way, but the moon would have 900 times the reflective area and be up to 900 times as bright at optimal position.   You'd also get full eclipses quite often.

The most devastating effect would be tides.   The tidal pull increases with the square of the distance from the earth's center, so the moon would be about 20 times as close to teh center and tides would be 400 times as great, so you're talking 1000 foot tides, maybe more.   This moon would also race across the sky fairly quick at that distance.

It's orbital speed would be about 16,000 Kilometers per hour and it's orbital distance, 2Pi*19,370, so in this theoretical the close moon would orbit the earth every 7.6 hours, about 3 times a day and we'd see the tides wash over the entire state of Florida, as one example, 6 times a day.   The waves would be big enough to destroy cities.  The oceans would be full of debris and soil - it would be pretty crazy.

Tides that strong might buckle the earth's surface.  You might see far more frequent volcanoes too - not quite sure on the mathematics of tidal volcanism, but the moon that close might just do it.

and, as in your question that close, the moon would be ahead of the tides, so the tides would tug on the moon, reducing the moon's speed and in effect, causing it to fall to the earth.   My calculations would be too rough to try, but it might only take a few thousand maybe a few tens of thousand of years for a moon that close to fall into the Roche limit and begin to break apart.  It wouldn't last long.

Then we'd maybe briefly have a ring system and the tides would stop, but I'd guess that chunks might break off and fall towards earth.   Tiny compared to the moon but large from our perspective - much larger than the Rock that killed the Dinos.   Probobly large enough to set the oceans boiling hot and maybe kill nearly all life on earth.

A Geosynchronous Orbit might be best if you want the moon close but not dangerous

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geosynchronous_orbit   But even in that orbit, it would probobly drift.   It would be difficult to keep it in perfect orbit and as it drifted it would pull very large tides, like 100 feet high, along with it.

We're better off with the moon where it is.

Answer (score 0):

The earth's orbital radius is about 150 million km, or 1 AU. The moon is already closer than that.

If you mean "an orbit smaller than the earth's diameter" it would put the moon inside the Roche limit, and the results would be quite exciting to watch. Too bad no one would survive.